# write something to already opened view, when coming back from the modal view

Tags: ios, swift

Edit something in the parent view, when moved from the child modal view. Should I use "viewWillAppear" or some other pre-defined functions for the view to be appeared in foreground..

Comment: whats your question here ..?, what you want to say here

Comment: Where's the problem? Did you tried something?

Comment: Can you explain in detail what exactly you want to do? Also add some code that you have written, so we can help you out.

Comment: You should use viewWillAppear when you want particular set of actions to happen every time your view appears, either via loading from memory, appearing after dismissing a chid view or after poping views above it in navigation stack.  Your code and a clear question will help us depict in a better way.

Comment: The question is "I segue to a modal view, and when coming back to the main view, I should call some function in the main view when I immediately close the modal view"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually plenty of ways to achieve what you want.

- One would be checking on `viewWillAppear`,
- another way is to create protocol, and call some protocol method when child is going to be dismissed.
- Also, you could have a property in the child class to    hold object
  reference to the parent, and when being dismissed call    some method
  on parent to notify the parent that the modal is being    dismissed.
- You could use `NotificationCenter`, and post a    notification, and
  handle the notification on the parent to update it, as well.

I don't know which one is the most suitable for you, if you give more context to the problem, I could clarify the answer. Good luck!

**Edit:**

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationcenter) is the official Apple documentation;

[Here](https://www.codebeaulieu.com/41/introduction-to-NSNotificationCenter-tutorial) you can find information about how to use the notifications and notification center.

You can search the Google for more on Notifications and NotificationCenter.